# Is a book shelf branch a branch?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am building a tree structure with 3 classes `Node`, `Leaf` and `Branch`.

1. `Node` is an abstract class for a tree node.
2. `Leaf` is derived from `Node` which cannot have children.
3. `Branch` is derived from `Node` which can have children and have a method `add(Node*)`

And I have concrete class like `Book` which is a `Leaf` and `BookShelf` which is a `Branch`. However, I double if the `BookShelf` is a `Branch` since the method `add(Node*)` is not valid when the `Node*` is not a book. Thus the `Branch` interface not works for `BookShelf`. How to handle those things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The impossibility of modeling collections well with inheritance was one of the primary motivations for inventing templates.

```
class Book {
    // ...
};

typedef std::vector<Book> book_shelf;
```

Done.

Comment: However I need the tree structure which works with a model/view framework and thus I can add a book in the book shelf in a tree view. Is there a better design or just assert the `Node*` is for a book? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to restrict `BookShelf::add()` to library items, you need to use generics (aka templates).  You will also need to define an abstract class `LibraryItem` to translate the concept of `Node`.

- `Branch` should be a template on type `T` (used to define the member list and `add`'s parameter)
- `LibraryItem` derives from `Node`
- `Book` derives from `Leaf` and `LibraryItem`
- `BookShelf` derives from `Branch<LibraryItem>` and `LibraryItem`

Comment: Great model! I think in your model, a `BookShelf` is not a `LibraryItem` as a `BookShelf` cannot be put on a `BookShelf`, and a `LibraryItem` can... So `BookShelf` derives from `Branch<LibraryItem>` and `Node`, or something like that...

Comment: Post another question with this and any other restriction. Maybe in real life it's obvious that a `BookShelf` can't be put in another `BookShelf`, but I didn't assume so. Most probably the answer will be too long for a comment, and quite different to this.

Comment: it's not my question, but it was already specified in the question: "method `add(Node*)` is not valid when the `Node*` is not a book" -- hence BookShelf cannot be put in. That's the only reason I mentioned it... And your answer (with one word changed) is already correct for that situation.